# Can't read xpath null html agility pack c#

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am new to html agility pack, and I am trying to read href attribute with link, but the problem is that it returns null. I don't know what I am doing wrong. That is my code:
[and I wanted to get this link from href html]https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOvt7.png

```
var html = webscrapper.Load($"https://www.fanatical.com/pl/search?search=yakuza%203");
var pierwszy = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/a");
    foreach(var a in pierwszy){
        Console.WriteLine($"https://www.fanatical.com/{a.Attributes["href"].Value}");
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to select with that strange xpath?

Comment: There's no way to diagnose this for you unless you tell us what you're trying to retrieve from that web page.

Comment: You can diagnose your xpath here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: @Prophet thanks for answering a hyperlink to a site, it starts with <a class="faux-block-link__overlay-link" href="/pl/game/yakuza-3-remastered"> and i wanted to get /pl/game/yakuza-3-remastered

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah you are right sorry I fixed it